Issues with local TCP streaming only displaying first frame
I am using my pi 5 to stream video as part of a larger project but running into issues with the basic setup.
On the Pi side I am running rpicam-vid -t 0 --listen -o tcp://0.0.0.0:8554
I can connect from both my laptop (ubuntu) and desktop (win11) in vlc with tcp/h264://192.168.0.23:8554 but it only displays an initial frame though in the command stdout (Maybe its using stderr?) that it seems to begin recording on connection but is for some reason failing to stream this to the client.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated, outputting to a file does seem to work correctly.

try adding the --inline --listen command line arguments documentation source
